# How does s[i]^=32 convert upper to lower case?

Tags: c++, string, uppercase, lowercase

```
int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "enter the string :" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        s[i] ^= 32;
    cout << "modified string is : " << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I saw this code which converts uppercase to lowercase on stackoverflow.

But I don't understand the line `s[i] = s[i]^32`.

How does it work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Comment: Don't worry about not understanding it.  It is not portable and should not be used.

Comment: Even for ASCII only, it rather *toggles* case and does bad things to characters other than alphabetic.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif here have a look at the ASCII table. `a` value in `dec` is 97, `A` value in `dec` is 65. The difference is 32.

Comment: @NathanOliver "it is not portable" is a bit of an exaggeration - it works for the ASCII letters A-Z, and there are lots of applications where that's an acceptable limitation. If you ran into this code that someone else wrote, wouldn't *you* like an explanation of what it's doing?

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure if you know that your use case is only going to be ASCII then it is not an issue but that should be documented in the code.  You should document when you place a limit on the cases something will work in when the C++  standard places no limit.  Also I do not think that there is any exaggeration in my statement.  C++ doesn't even require ASCII to be used or that characters are sequential.

Comment: It's just an overly "clever" code trick that sacrifices a little portability to accomplish nothing. That's a very bad tradeoff.

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't say you were *wrong*, of course the standard does not mandate ASCII. But when's the last time you used a system that didn't? And if I were working with a string that was already guaranteed to consist solely of upper-case ASCII characters, I certainly wouldn't add extra documentation for that one line of code, it would just be noise. I certainly agree that there are better methods available, however.

Comment: @ChristianHackl in the olden days, this kind of code was common. It's useful to know why it works, because that will inform you when it doesn't.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Of course, the knowledge can't hurt. Still, a lot of things were different in the olden days, not all of them for the better.

Comment: @MarkRansom In the _olden days_ we had _punch cards_ around :P (And even EBCDIC was around prior to ASCII IIRC)

Comment: PLZZ give me an example thats how i can understand it easily

Comment: So, `toupper()` is a single line because all it needs to account for is ASCII?!!! Of course, not. You aren't using ASCII, you are using ISO-8859-1 or something else. What does this code trick do to ÿ and ß?

Answer (score 20):

`^=` is the [exclusive-or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) assignment operator. 32 is 100000 in binary, so `^= 32` switches the fifth bit in the destination. In ASCII, lower and upper case letters are 32 positions apart, so this converts lower to upper case, and also the other way.

But it only works for ASCII, not for Unicode for example, and only for letters. To write portable C++, you should not assume the character encoding to be ASCII, so please don't use such code. @πάντα ῥεῖs answer shows a way to do it properly.

Comment: Code like this should never be used.

Comment: It only works with letters in the ASCII code.  Try it with other symbols.

Comment: And it works nicely only with alphabetic characters. It will do crazy things to others.

Comment: @magic-sudo: There are a lot of ASCII characters besides a-z and A-Z.

Comment: It will probably lead to hard to trace bugs later on.

Comment: You should make it clear that lowercase and uppercase letters are 32 positions apart *only* if ASCII or something compatible is being used, and the C++ standard does not guarantee that.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I've written it only works with ASCII, but didn't mention the standard because it does not talk about character encodings at all.

Comment: @alain: Well, that's my point. You talk about the 32 positions before hinting that ASCII cannot be assumed. Which, to a beginner, may sound as if the statement *"lower and upper case letters are 32 positions apart"* is universally correct in C++.

Comment: @EmmanuelMathi-Amorim "never be used" is more useful if you propose an alternative.

Comment: @alain THX for the flowers. I appreciate your answer explains the underlying mechanics.

Comment: PLZZ give me an example thats how i can understand it easily

Comment: @RashedSami For example, 'A' has the number 65. `^= 32` has the effect of adding 32 to 65 = 97. 97 is the number for 'a'. You could read about [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) and [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) on wikipedia. Skip the history parts, start reading at 'Computer science' and 'Counting in binary'. Or else please say what exactly you don't understand.

Answer (score 16):

> How does it work?

Let's see for ASCII value `'A'`:

`'A'` is binary `1000001`

XORed with 32 (binary `100000`)

yields any value where the upper character indicating bit isn't set:

`1000001`
XOR
`100000`
= `1100001` == `'a'` in ASCII.

---

Any sane and portable c or c++ application should use [`tolower()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower):

```
int main()
{
    string s;
    cout<<"enter the string :"<<endl;
    cin>>s;
    for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++) s[i] = tolower( (unsigned char)s[i] );
                                     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    cout<<"modified string is : "<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The `s[i]=s[i]^32` (cargo cult) magic, relies on [*ASCII table*](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) specific mapping to numeric `char` values.

There are other `char` code tables like e.g. [*EBCDIC*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code)
, where the

```
 s[i]=s[i]^32
```

method miserably fails to retrieve the corresponding lower case letters.

---

There's a more sophisticated c++ version of converting to lower case characters shown in the reference documentation page of [`std::ctype::tolower()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/tolower).

Comment: `ctype` is a class template, not a class, and `tolower()` is a non-static member function.

Comment: @Barry THX for pointing that out. Fixed to fall back to the straight c version. (well that invalidates _"Any sane and portable c++ application"_ a bit now).

Comment: After all, this is C++. Why wouldn't we have [three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower)  [different](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower) [functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/tolower) named `tolower()`. I guess 4 if you count the range overload of the `ctype` one.

Comment: Portable code would be `s[i] = tolower( (unsigned char)s[i] )` or `s[i] = tolower( s[i], std::locale() );`

Comment: ^@M.M Adopted your 1st version.

Comment: @RashedSami _"PLZZ give me an example"_ There are already examples (check the links as well). I don't get what you don't understand from all the reference material given in the answers to your question. `s[i]=s[i]^32` does an _exclusive or_ bitwise operation for `s[i]` and `32`. This relies on the specific layout of the ASCII character table, and the relation of upper and lower case characters ordered in it.

Comment: Still not correct if you want your program to work for non-English text.  Case transformations may change the length of a string (e.g., German `ß` uppercases to `SS`) or be context-sensitive (e.g., Greek `Σ` lowercases to `ς` at the end of a word but `σ` elsewhere).  It would have made more sense for C++ to have casing functions that work on whole `std::string` objects.  With a locale argument, of course, because it has to deal with the fact that Turkish has `I`/`ı` and `İ`/`i` case pairs, in contrast to other Latin-script languages that use `I`/`i`.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, like its predecessor C, a `char` is a numeric type.  This is after all how characters are represented on the hardware and these languages don't hide that from you.

In ASCII, letters have the useful property that the difference between an uppercase and a lowercase letter is a single binary bit: the 5th bit (if we start numbering from the right starting at 0).

Uppercase A is represented by the byte `0b01000001` (`0x41` in hex), and lowercase a is represented by the byte `0b01100001` (`0x61` in hex). Notice that the only difference between uppercase and lowercase A is the fifth bit.  This pattern continues from B to Z.

So, when you do `^= 32` (which, incidentally, is 2 to the 5th power) on a number that represents an ASCII character, what that does is toggle the 5th bit - if it is 0, it becomes 1, and vice versa, which changes the character from upper to lower case and vice versa.

Comment: ... if your C++ implementation uses ASCII.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I specifically named ASCII as the character set I was talking about in my answer (since it is the same as OP's question)

Comment: Yes, but you failed to mention that perhaps your C++ implementation does not use ASCII at all.

Comment: PLZZ give me an example thats how i can understand it easily

Comment: @RashedSami This answer *has* an example. Did you read it before commenting?