# How to check string whether contain some alphabets using SSE

Tags: c, sse

I tried to use SSE to accelerate task:

In high level aspect:

```cpp
string a = "^&a&*";
string b = "abcdef";
bool c = a_contain_any_alphabet_in_b(a, b);
```

More detail using SSE(pseudo code):

```cpp
a = _mm_set_epi8('^', .....);
b = _mm_set_epi8('a', .....);
mask = _mm_cmpestrm (a, la, b, lb, imm8); // _SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_ANY toggle

... and then extract mask
```

My problem is what if my `b` contain more than 128 bits?
The situation such as I want to check string `a` contain any alphabet(a~zA~Z) which recorded in `b`. But set of alphabets are `8*52` bits which greater than `128`.

The naive approach I figured out is to separate `b` into many `__mm128i`.

```cpp
mask1 = _mm_cmpestrm (a, la, b1, lb, imm8);
mask2 = _mm_cmpestrm (a, la, b2, lb, imm8);
...
and do some operation with all masks
```

I'm wondering are there any approach to do smarter?

Comment: Do you always want to check for `a~zA~Z` or does this need to be customizable?

Comment: A contiguous range can be checked efficiently using a single sub and compare range-check trick.  See my SIMD answer on [Convert a String In C++ To Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37151084).  My answer on [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585515) shows a scalar version of detecting an alphabetic character.  Just remove the `y |= 0x20` if you only care about one case, or keep it if you want to detect any alphabetic.

Comment: @chtz actually I also want to add comma into set

Comment: @Steven Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63940531/edit) your question to describe the actual problem you want to solve. It's still not clear to me if you always want to check for the same set.

Comment: Yes, I always want to check for the same set. This set contain `a~zA~Z ` and comma