# Cleanest way to check input char is between 0~9 in Assembly

Tags: assembly, digits, micro-optimization, riscv, atoi

The problem is to convert string to int in RISC-V

if any char that is not 0~9 exist, return -1 immediately

but I wonder if there's any way to check it by using minimum instruction

my way is to put 48 and 57 (which correspond to 0~9 in ASCII) in temp register,
and use 2 branches, firstly check <=57, then check >=48

But it use too many instruction, and require additional temp register to store 48 and 57.  Is there any other efficient way?

Comment: Yes, since you have to subtract `'0'` anyway, do that and then unsigned compare  `c <= 9` or `c < 10`.  See [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585515) for the range-check trick.  [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057) is an x86 asm implementation of a loop using that idea.  It should translate well to RISC-V; try writing it in C and using a compiler.

Comment: I was curious what I could get GCC / clang to emit for a C version; turns out not as good as my hand-written x86 asm so I wrote up an answer.  Looks like some missed optimizations for the RISC-V version, too. BTW, gcc/clang know the range-check trick I mentioned; you don't usually need to implement it manually.  But combining it with `-= '0'` to convert to an integer is useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since you have to subtract `'0'` anyway, do that and then unsigned compare  `c <= 9` or `c < 10`.  See [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536362/what-is-the-idea-behind-32-that-converts-lowercase-letters-to-upper-and-vice/54585515#54585515) for the range-check trick.

We can do this in C and then see how it compiles, as a starting point for a compact RISC-V implementation.  This C is structured like the asm in [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309749/nasm-assembly-convert-input-to-integer/49548057#49548057), in hopes that GCC or clang will use similar loop structure.  If you translate it by hand, you might want this kind of loop structure, or tweak it for better software-pipelining on an in-order RISC-V, especially to hide load-use latency.  This loop structure is great on a modern x86 where OoO speculative exec hides branch and load-use latency.

```
// C intentionally written exactly like hand-written asm
// Translate this to asm by hand, including the loop structure.
// or compile it if you want more bloated asm.

unsigned str_to_uint(const unsigned char *p) {
    unsigned dig = *p - '0';
    unsigned total = dig;  // peel first iter, optimize away the  + 0 * 10
    if (total < 10)        // <10 can share a constant with *10
        goto loop_entry;
    else // fall through to the uncommon case of no valid digits
        return 0;

    do {
        total = total*10 + dig;
     loop_entry:            // branch target = loop entry point
        dig = *++p - '0';
    } while(dig < 10);

    return total;
}
```

I skip the `total * 10 + dig` on the first iteration using a taken branch, so we might as well have that be our entry into the loop to minimize the amount of total code.

Another option would be to peel *another* loop iteration fall into the top of the loop.  This is what GCC and clang choose, when compiling with `-O3` or `-O2`.  With `-Os` gcc de-optimizes it to a loop with a `j` at the bottom and `btgu` break in the middle.  ([Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaIAEydSq9ABk8tTADk9AI0zEQvAA6pphJbU079Rk3dPRTpLaztdR2deWXkQ2gYCZmICXz0DYxk5TAVvROSCMNsHJxcZJJS0/0zpCsKrYsjS7gBKGVRtYmQOAHJtWk9ga3QAalriMSIxbSsCCDQBghH%2BweGR5ARkkYAqVxaRgFIAdgAhA4AGAEERm%2BWBvCHMUfxgQ4BmABEd1xGAWhGwD1zoCDm8zldbndVk8RkQkqx3l8XqCTjcAPRokauTByEZUPDEWojQhOUgjVCuRS6PAAL0wI2YAHdmABPEbnHYjTjnC7XW54KgjCBwtjvdRc877SG3DFi7nrERjTbEenMdZ0WoiJaMwgIHbc3nS27AVBEEasVAUsSqAjEFkow23OSyEayqhsBEEBDEDrAPVmr30/poXS6OgKl2oQW0VAjABubDwzwehGkjqNKoInVo7IdV3TI3QseO4L5RpFCNBXwr23lB0MqORYIL5strmt9DtICNRtl9mIIg2sOSwEwSyrrYpIxtdqxqFmLduL0RO3rZwbP3%2BgOBPTzZcORy%2BjIQeHYEGXoPF3Jae4LmezsNNbFvh95b6uKwea3Gk1QYlmYieLorhngsRKfo8owbFsuz7CWBYQWsFYrjyzYQrciEwsge6QjQxDCk%2BrBVhyKJCthny7H8AJAoCcFvOoE4AJzvKirhrmuN6nIuNzIRONZ1g26w4bcxwfHeY4PhWL5iVcPRtKwIA9AArD0pAGECqmoIp4rSB0XT0vWbycKpBCKeccltAA1iAbxvAAdLZjlOc5ABsQiKdwqnqeZpBaT0qnSCA5ykKZGltHAsBICGrinqSFDzKgwGxc4yDEHg0jIHGAAchjBfirAEE4gUQPYZmqfYVjJCyinGaQIa6DaADytCsNVGmkFgugiMA7BlR1BI5IocaYIF7WYAAHjk2iFTVqmzHIfWsHg/ZVZoWCzSFaW6LNbQ0PQTBsBwPD8IIwiiCAEhiFIS32IFkBtBS8Sjb8jVvDcvw0NSBAfQODW/O483EAF2S5MoEBmFUBgmGYRQRFEghBF4dCQwjHhI7QsMlM4JixINeR1CjOMg/E%2BQpJjTTY%2BUBSE1TZMNHDpScG0umdN0XDyYpKlqX1fkAEoAJIMOovwAGojMAyDICMWV2YYdkchAuCECQhyGEZZKaEl7DEKrRn7OoJllS0Vk2fZznm45bkKT0nmkNtSnBd5mmKQFQUhUbpARYgKCJTF2vkJQ0XJSAxBxm8hiS2dwCkPlhWEpQpXtRVtBVRt9VNS1bU%2BZ13W9e1%2BAqrkw2jT5E1TTNPS1fN1s%2BTdA52mtvS1baeDbZXckx3QjAsL1x0CIYQjdRdkhCMtd0QA9lLeM9r3vZ9hA/cwf0A/QTjA3E3gqGoNMw/TWOo8E3g04j8Tk/DRMb3QpOpFo6SCLjoMJHUZ%2BM7TN9%2BFDb8v9jzN6WzTPuWUl5HmikBZC1FiMUO4cJbrCjkKW0/RLL7EVvgIgOtDImBGJrP2ThdaGH1obMKJtbIOQtubQBtsna%2BRdjIN2oVzLG0AYYYB7U/KEIYW0YahJN7cCAA%3D%3D)).  I don't know any `-march=` RISC-V arch or tune options to try.

So if you want a good balance of code-size and efficiency (especially for the often-common case of 1 or 2 digit numbers), you should probably "compile" it by hand.

GCC uses `(x<<3) + (x<<1)` to multiply by 10; clang uses `mul` (and inside the loop does share a constant between `mul` and the `bltu` loop branch.  Unfortunately outside the loop clang compares against `9`, like `9 < total`, so it needs both constants.  (Does RISC-V have a `bge` `<=` compare?  IDK, TODO / edit welcome on whether this is a missed optimization or not).