# strcasecmp implementation not printing

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, x86-64

I'm working on a little project where I have to recode a function from the lib C. Actually I'm working on `strcasecmp`:

```
BITS 64

%include "minilib.inc"

section .text

my_strcasecmp:
init:
    mov r10b, [rdi]
    mov r11b, [rsi]
    jmp while

while:
    cmp r10b, 0
    je end
    cmp r11b, 0
    je end
    cmp r10b, 90
    jle checkfirstup
    cmp r11b, 90
    jle checksecondup
    jmp strcasecmp

strcasecmp:
    cmp r10b, r11b
    jne end
    inc rdi
    inc rsi
    jmp init

checkfirstup:
    cmp r10b, 65
    jge r10btolowcase
    jmp checksecondup

r10btolowcase:
    add r10b, 32
    jmp while

checksecondup:
    cmp r11b, 65
    jge r11btolowcase
    jmp strcasecmp

r11btolowcase:
    add r11b, 32
    jmp while

end:
    movzx rax, r10b
    movzx rbx, r11b
    sub rax, rbx
    ret
```

and this is the code in c :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int my_strcasecmp(const char *string1, const char *string2); /* Prototype */

int main(void)
{
    char *str1 = "S";
    char *str2 = "S";
    int result;

    result = strcasecmp(str1, str2);

    if (result == 0)
        printf("Strings compared equal.\n");
    else if (result < 0)
        printf("\"%s\" is less than \"%s\".\n", str1, str2);
    else
        printf("\"%s\" is greater than \"%s\".\n", str1, str2);

    return 0;}
```

when I try my strcasecmp I always have "nanana is greater than nanana" and I don't understand why.

How can I fix this?

Comment: All this branching is a lot more complicated than necessary, besides the fact that the code is in a weird order where it's hard to see if both input chars are case-normalized before moving to the next.  It doesn't help that this is using literal numbers instead of `'Z'` or whatever.  [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585515) shows and links some ways to case-normalize ASCII with a few instructions each (MOV/OR/SUB/CMP pluse one branch or cmov)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when the first char is not in [A,Z], you immediately jump to *checksecondup* where you only ever check the lower bound for the second char. The `cmp r11b, 90` was never performed at that point! (It triggers an unwanted `add r11b, 32`.)

The solution is to LCase both characters independently:

```
  ...
  cmp r10b, 65
  jb  Next
  cmp r10b, 90
  ja  Next
  add r10b, 32
Next:
  cmp r11b, 65
  jb  Next_
  cmp r11b, 90
  ja  Next_
  add r11b, 32
Next_:
  cmp r10b, r11b
  ...
```

Comment: And how do you go to Next_ when no one are upcase ?

Comment: @Lewisuehjo: follow the tests: if none are uppercase, either the `jb` or the `ja` must be taken to jump to `Next` and then the same to jump to `Next_`.