# Compare for equal to uppercase and lowercase versions of the same letter

Tags: assembly, x86-16, case-insensitive, emu8086

Hello currently I'm doing a project in asm language and I came up with this code:

```
mov ah, 07h 
int 21h 
mov bl,al     

cmp bl, 'w'
je  up
cmp bl, 'W'
je  up
```

The code is about entering a letter and jumping to another function. The thing I want to do is to compare it even if it is in either uppercase or lowercase. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: `'w'` and `'W'` are just numbers. `'w'` == `'W' + 32`, look at an ASCII table for more info.

Comment: yes but i want to also lessen the lines of the code is there a way to compare with 'w' or 'W' somewhat like this cmp bl, 'w' or 'W]'

Comment: 8086 has no OPCODE for doing 2 compares in one cycle. Your code cannot be shorten more.

Comment: @paladin: How does `'W' + 32` help?  Unlike `'W' | 32`, that's not idempotent so it doesn't fold both inputs to one value to check for.  (As in Sep's answer).  Or I guess you weren't trying to propose an optimization, just saying it's *not* possible.  (Which is correct in general for two arbitrary values, and the optimization here takes an extra instruction before the `cmp`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the uppercase letters [A,Z] (ASCII codes [65,90]) differ from the lowercase letters [a,z] (ASCII codes [97,122]) by 32, and because of how the ASCII table is organised, all the lowercase letters have their bit5 set while none of the uppercase letters have their bit5 set.

### Make it case-insensitive

Before comparing you can `or` the character code with 32, and then you'll need just one comparison.

```
mov ah, 07h 
int 21h 
mov bl, al     

or  al, 32     ; Make case-insensitive
cmp al, 'w'    ; Only comparing lowercase, but accepting both cases
je  up
```

What this `or al, 32` instruction does is:

- if AL is [A,Z] it becomes [a,z]
- if AL is [a,z] it remains [a,z]

Comment: Also equally importantly, no non-letter ASCII code can become `w` either; `'W'` and `'w'` are the *only* inputs such that `c | 0x20 == 'w'`.  Setting or clearing the lower-case bit doesn't make non-letters into letters or vice-versa, so in general this is a useful trick for things like checking if a character is a letter of the alphabet.  ([What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585515) has more details)