# how to properly calculate sum of digits from specific place in file? (YASM 8086)

Tags: assembly, emu8086, yasm

I have one line of text in my input file, which is divided into **six** columns. Columns are separated from each other by a **semicolon**.

Here is input file example:

`A1;example;10;0;55;2.44`

I am looking only into **third** column number. In this case it would be number `10`, so the sum of its digits is `1`. According to the task requirements, the sum has to be `7`

I read the line, save it into buffer. Then byte by byte I move to the place where third comumn starts.

```
    ; Save line into buffer
    call procGetLine
    
    ; Skip one column
    mov di, inputBuffer
    .whileNotSemicolon:
        cmp di, byte ';'
        je .semicolon
        inc di
        jmp .whileNotSemicolon
        .semicolon:
            inc di

    ; Do some calculations with second column and move to the start of third column
    ; ............

    ; Call function that calculates sum of number digits in third column
    call procDigitsSum
    cmp [digitsSum], word 7
    je .isSeven
```

`procDigitsSum` function:

```
    procDigitsSum
    push si
    push ax
    push dx
    push cx
    push bx

        mov [digitsSum], word 0
        mov si, 0
        .loop:
            mov cl, [di]
            inc di

            cmp cl, byte ';'
            je .columnEnd

            ; ASCIIZ for using it in function later
            mov byte [thirdColumnNumber+si], cl     
            mov byte [thirdColumnNumber+si+1], 0    
            inc si
            jmp .loop

        .columnEnd
            mov dx, thirdColumnNumber
            mov di, dx
            .secondLoop:
                ; Guessing mistake lies somewhere here
                mov dl, [di]
                inc di
                cmp dl, byte 0
                je .endLoop

                add [digitsSum], dl
                add [digitsSum], byte 30h

                jmp .secondLoop

        .endLoop
    pop bx
    pop cx
    pop dx
    pop ax
    pop si
    ret
```

`procGetLine` function just in case, however it seems to work fine:

```
procGetLine:
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push si

        mov bx, [inputFileDescriptor]
        mov si, 0

        .loop
            call procFGetChar
            cmp ax, 0
            je .endOfFile
            jc .endOfFile

            mov [inputBuffer+si], cl
            inc si

            cmp cl, 0Ah
            je .endOfLine

            jmp .loop

        .endOfFile:
            mov [lastLine], byte 1
        .endOfLine:
            mov [inputBuffer+si], byte '$'
            mov [bytesRead], si

    pop si
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret
```

Comment: `add [digitsSum], byte 30h` should of course be a `sub`. Also you do not really need to copy the value to a buffer, you can just add the digits as you see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ; Skip one column
> mov di, inputBuffer
> .whileNotSemicolon:
>     cmp di, byte ';'
>     je .semicolon
>     inc di
>     jmp .whileNotSemicolon
>     .semicolon:
>         inc di
> ```

This code can't possibly *skip one column*! The `cmp di, byte ';'` makes no sense. It compares the pointer instead of the byte that the pointer points at. You need:

```
.whileNotSemicolon:
    cmp  [di], byte ';'
    je   .semicolon
    inc  di
    jmp  .whileNotSemicolon
    .semicolon:
        inc di
```

But an even better solution tries to minimize the branching like in next code:

```
.whileNotSemicolon:
    mov  al, [di]
    inc  di
    cmp  al, ';'
    jne  .whileNotSemicolon
.semicolon:
```

> In this case it would be number 10, so the sum of it's digits is **1**. According to *the task requirements*, the sum has to be **7**

I don't see where this 7 should come from!

---

Your post doesn't mention this, but what are the chances that you are not solving a task related to [this extremely similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74478881/how-to-skip-word-in-yasm-8086) where the 3rd, 4th, and 5th columns contain numbers in the range [-100,100].
Knowing that the 3rd column can only contain {-0123456789;}, the task to sum the digits comprises:

- loading a byte from the 3rd column
- converting the character into the corresponding digit subtracting 48
- if it was the minus<sup>1</sup> (ASCII=45), the result will be -3 which will have produced a carry on `sub al, '0'`
- if it was the semicolon (ASCII=59), the result will be 11 which is above 9

```
; IN (di) OUT (di)
procDigitsSum
    push ax
    push cx
    xor  cx, cx
    xor  ax, ax
.loop:
    add  cx, ax
.minus:
    mov  al, [di]
    inc  di
    sub  al, '0'
    jb   .minus          ; It's a minus
    cmp  al, 9
    jbe  .loop           ; It's a digit
.above:                  ; It's a semicolon
    mov  [digitsSum], cx
    pop  cx
    pop  ax
    ret                  ; DI points at next column
```

<sup>1</sup> If whitespace were allowed, it would follow the same path as the minus did.