# X64 Assembly uppercase function

Tags: assembly, x86-64, uppercase

I'm learning assembly and, while trying to create a string uppercase conversion function, that receives a string and returns a UPPERCASEd string, I'm stuck on the following code:

```
asm_func3:
        mov             rbp, [rax]              ; stores argument received in rbp
        push            rcx                     ; prepare rcx for use
        xor             rcx,rcx                 ; zero counter
        
_toupper:
        cmp             byte [rbp+rcx], 61h     ; is lowercase ascii?
        jl              _toupper_next           ; no, go to next char

        cmp             byte [rbp+rcx], 7Ah     ; is lowercase ascii?
        jg              _toupper_next           ; no, go to next char
        
        sub             byte [rbp+rcx], 20h     ; subtract 32 to convert lowercase to uppercase

_toupper_next:  
        inc             rcx                     ; next char
        cmp             byte [rbp+rcx], 0h      ; is end of string?
        jne             _toupper                ; start again


_toupper_end:
        mov             rax, rbp                ; copy the result to return register
        pop             rcx                     ; release rcx
        ret
```

I'm getting a SIGBUS on the line:

```
cmp             byte [rbp+rcx], 61h     ; is lowercase ascii?
```

I'm calling this function from a C prog as follows:

```
printf("%s", asm_func3("abcdef\n"));
```

I suspect I'm not handling RBP correctly but I exhausted all my information sources. Can someone help me?

Comment: The C calling convention does not pass argument in `rax` so the `mov rbp, [rax] ` is already wrong. Also `rbp` should be preserved.

Comment: Write the function in C and observe what the compiler does; then follow same parameter passing, etc.. in your hand written function.  Also, you can read about the calling convention for your environment, here's a document that collects many.  https://www.dyncall.org/docs/manual/manualse11.html

Comment: `push        rcx   ; prepare rcx for use` - that's an odd comment.  In the standard calling conventions, RCX is call-clobbered, RBP is call-preserved.  You can trash the caller's RCX without saving it first.  Unlike RBP.  So use RAX as the base and RCX as the index (or better just copy the pointer to RAX and RCX and increment the pointer while leaving RAX around as the return value).  You have plenty of call-preserved registers, especially if you write your function inefficiently like this to not load the byte into a register.

Comment: Re: Erik's suggestion of looking at compiler output, see [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) . Also, [Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4429398) compares the two widely-used x86-64 calling conventions.

Answer (score 1):

The working code:

```
    ; Function: asm_func3
; Purpose: Convert all lowercase letters in a source string to uppercase and store the result in a destination buffer.
; Parameters:
;   rdi: Pointer to the source null-terminated string.
;   rsi: Pointer to the destination buffer.
; Returns:
;   rax: Pointer to the destination buffer containing the converted string.

asm_func3:
        ; Preserve the base pointer, as it's callee-saved.
        push  rbp                     

        ; Initialize rcx (our character offset counter) to 0.
        xor   rcx, rcx                 

_toupper:
        ; Load the next character from the source string into the al register.
        mov   al, byte [rdi]           

        ; Check if we've reached the end of the source string.
        cmp   al, 0h                   
        je    _toupper_end              ; If yes, jump to the function's end sequence.

        ; Check if the character is a lowercase letter.
        ; ASCII values: 'a' is 61h and 'z' is 7Ah.
        cmp   al, 61h                  
        jl    _toupper_next             ; If character is less than 'a', skip to the next character.
        cmp   al, 7Ah                  
        jg    _toupper_next             ; If character is greater than 'z', skip to the next character.
        
        ; Convert the lowercase character to uppercase.
        ; ASCII conversion: Uppercase letters are 32 less than their lowercase counterparts.
        sub   al, 20h                  

_toupper_next:   
        ; Store the (potentially converted) character into the destination buffer.
        mov   byte [rsi + rcx], al     

        ; Increment both the source pointer and our character offset counter.
        inc   rdi                      
        inc   rcx                      

        ; Jump back to the start of the loop to process the next character.
        jmp   _toupper                 

_toupper_end:
        ; Null-terminate the destination buffer.
        mov   byte [rsi + rcx], 0h     

        ; Set the return value to the base address of the destination buffer.
        mov   rax, rsi                 

        ; Restore the base pointer and return from the function.
        pop   rbp                      
        ret
```

Comment: You forgot the triple-backticks to make a code block.  Also, you don't need to save/restore RBP since your function doesn't modify it, just like it doesn't modify RBX or R12-R15.

Comment: A nice trick to getting the destination 0-terminated without an extra instruction is to only check the loop condition after copying a byte.  So you end up checking if `0` is an upper-case character, but it isn't so it gets copied unmodified.  Implicit-length C-string functions always process at least 1 byte (the terminating `0`) so we can put the loop condition at the bottom where it belongs (*[Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)*) without an extra check at the top.

Comment: (Your code looks *correct*, just not as efficient as it could be.  Of course if you cared about efficiency, you'd use at most one branch like `lea`/`cmp` for the range-check, and maybe `cmov` instead of branching.  Or you'd be using SSE2 to process 8 or 16 bytes in parallel once you reach an alignment boundary, unless your strings are usually only a few bytes long. [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585515) / [Convert a String In C++ To Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37151084))

Comment: Thank you, @PeterCordes, you're giving me a lot of useful info to study :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the comments. After reviewing the documentation I managed to have the code below working. Any additional comments?

```
asm_func3:
        push            rbp                     ; must be preserved
        xor             rcx,rcx                 ; zero counter
        mov             dl, byte [rdi+rcx]      ; copy one byte

_toupper:
        cmp             dl, byte 61h            ; is lowercase ascii?
        jl              _toupper_next           ; no, go to next char 
        cmp             dl, byte 7Ah            ; is lowercase ascii?
        jg              _toupper_next           ; no, go to next char
        sub             dl, 20h                 ; subtract 32 to convert lowercase to uppercase

_toupper_next:   
        mov             byte [rsi+rcx], dl      ; save byte on rsi
        inc             rcx                     ; next char
        mov             dl, byte [rdi+rcx]      ; copy one more byte
        cmp             dl, 0h                  ; is end of string?
        jne             _toupper                ; start again
        mov             rax, rsi                ; copy rsi to rax to return
        pop             rbp                     ; restore rbp
        ret
```

Right now I just need to figure out how to clear RSI, to remove any "garbage" from previous calls.

Comment: This may do something bad if the *first* character is the 0-terminator of the string (ie when an empty string is passed in), especially if the next character (data that doesn't belong to this string) isn't 0. Also I don't really understand what you're talking about regarding `rsi` and garbage

Comment: Thank you, Harold, I moved the check for null to the begin of the looping. When the function is called `rsi` has some content from a previous printf call: `1: (char *) $rdi = 0x55555555606d "Hello from asm_func3\n" 2: (char *) $rsi = 0x5555555592a0 "Return of asm_func2: 21\n"`